# how to use jQuery to adjust div size to its sibling?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="left_and_right">
    <div class="left"> .. something .. </div>
    <div class="right"> .. something .. </div>
    <div class="left"> .. something .. </div>
    <div class="right"> .. something .. </div>
    <div class="left"> .. something .. </div>
    <div class="right"> .. something .. </div>
</div>
```

say I have a main div with alternating three left and right divs.
What I'd like to do is:

when page is loaded, set width of each "left" to its 'right'.

so, I tried:
`$("div[class=left]").attr('height', $(this).next().attr('height'))`

which doesn't work.

What is proper way to find a element's sibling and use its attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("div.left").each(function(){
    $(this).height($(this).next().height());
});
```

Comment: don't use `attr()` for height... use `css()` or `height()` methods

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('div[class="left"]').each(function(){
   $(this).css('height',$(this).next().height());
});
```